# ggplot: Manually add legends for aesthetics that are not mapped

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a barplot overlayed with dots where both have separate legends. Also, I want to choose the color of the bars and the size of the dots using the arguments outside `aes()`. As both are not mapped, no legend is produced.

**1) How can I add a legend manually for both fill and size?**

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(group = 1:3,    
                prop = 1:3 )

ggplot(d, aes(x=group, y=prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") +
  geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]

This is what I came up with: I used dummy mappings and modified the legend according to my needs afterwards. But this approach appears clumsy to me.

**2) Is there a manual way to say: Add a legend with this title, these shapes, these colors etc.?**

```
d <- data.frame(dummy1="d1",
                dummy2="d2",
                group = 1:3,    
                prop = 1:3 )


ggplot(d, aes(x=group, y=prop, fill=dummy1, size=dummy2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="fill legend", label="fill label") +
  scale_size_discrete(name="size legend", label="size label")
```

[image]

Above I mapped `fill` to `dummy1`. So I would expect `scale_fill_discrete` to alter this legend. But it appears to modify the `size` legend instead.

**3) I am not sure what went wrong here. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say "Also, I want to choose the color of the bars and the size of the dots using the arguments outside aes()". Is it something you're trying to do or is it something that you have to do given how ggplot works?

If it's the latter, one solution is as under -

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(group = 1:3,    
                prop = 1:3 )

ggplot(d, aes(x=group, y=prop)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",aes( fill="label")) +
    geom_point(aes(size='labelsize')) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = 'label', values = 'red')+
    scale_size_manual(breaks = 'labelsize', values = 5)
```

Comment: The latter. I guess I was wrong that I have to set size and fill outside aes. Thanks.