# Adding legend to barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

Can someone tell me how to add a legend to my barplot that should only consist of one colour without accounting for several groups? Since my plot shows four different groups that activated a specific amount of regulation strategies, I only want the legend to indicate it is the "general strategy use" expressend by all bars of the graph.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
group <- c (1,2,3,4)
means <- c(2.57, 2.32, 2.76, 2.61)
sds <- c(0.24, 0.21, 0.26, 0.24)
Problemtype <- c("No Problem", "Motivational Problem", "Knowledge Problem", "Both Problems")


barplot <- ggplot(df, aes(Problemtype, means)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", fill="lightblue") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sds, ymax = means + sds), width=0.2)

barplot + labs(y="Overall Regulation (K 95%)", x = "Problemtype") + theme_classic()
```

Comment: You need to put the color assignment inside an `aes` call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot: Manually add legends for aesthetics that are not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635173/ggplot-manually-add-legends-for-aesthetics-that-are-not-mapped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I added line that creates the df. Then I added a new variable to the df. I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but it allows you to add legend with one color. Then you can add scale_fill_manual to paint it with 'lightblue'. Hope that solves it.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4) 
group <- c (1,2,3,4)
means <- c(2.57, 2.32, 2.76, 2.61)
sds <- c(0.24, 0.21, 0.26, 0.24) 
Problemtype <- c("No Problem", "Motivational Problem", "Knowledge Problem", "Both Problems")
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = id, group = group, means = means, sds = sds,
Problemtype = Problemtype)
df['one_col'] = 'General Strategy Use'

barplot <- df %>%    
group_by(one_col) %>%   
ggplot( aes(Problemtype, means)) +    
geom_bar(stat="identity", aes( fill = one_col))+   
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sds, ymax = means + sds), width=0.2)

barplot + labs(y="Overall Regulation (K 95%)", x = "Problemtype") +   
theme_classic()+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue"))
```

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y94wT.png)